# Invalid generic declaration when using FRAME macro pallet::error

Tags: pallet, frame, macro

I want to add custom error types to a working pallet (permalink [duniter-wot/src/lib.rs](https://git.duniter.org/nodes/rust/duniter-v2s/-/blob/e714b76c30a5bde7a073681cd6fdfdcdcae75807/pallets/duniter-wot/src/lib.rs)). In this current state, `cargo check` pass successfully.

According to Substrate documentation [frame-macros/#palleterror](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/frame-macros/#palleterror), I'm adding inside the `#[frame_support::pallet]` block a `#[pallet::error]` macro with an enumeration named `Error` with a generic type like:

```rust
#[pallet::error]
pub enum Error<T> {
    /// variant one
    VariantOne,
    /// variant two
    VariantTwo,
}
```

But as soon as I do this, `cargo check` returns a long (> 700 lines) error trace in which the first element is:

```
error: Invalid generic declaration, trait is defined with instance but generic use none
  --> pallets/duniter-wot/src/lib.rs:99:20
   |
99 |     pub enum Error<T> {
   |                    ^
```

The question, more than "how to fix this" would be "how am I supposed to understand this hint" and "what resources/tools/documentation could help me debug myself".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your pallet is instantiatable. This requires you to additionally pass in the instance type like such. In the easiest case it looks like this:

```rust
#[pallet::error]
pub enum Error<T, I = ()> {
```

Making a pallet instantiatable is useful when you plan on having more than one instance deployed within the same runtime.

> what resources/tools/documentation could help me debug myself

For me personally it is enough to read examples from the Substrate repo. For example [pallet-referenda](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/1f720c11b90d45bba0c4ddad60d3b9a27ca85441/frame/referenda/src/lib.rs#L352).